# Pandas resample().size() returns different object types depending on sample frequency

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have Pandas DataFrame, which I am summarizing using the *groupby()*, *resample()* and *size()* functions:

```
freq = upgrade.groupby("UPGRADESTRATEGY")
type(freq)
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>

print(freq.resample('Q'))
DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby [freq=<QuarterEnd: startingMonth=12>, axis=0, closed=right, label=right, convention=e, base=0]

print(freq.resample('Y'))
DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby [freq=<YearEnd: month=12>, axis=0, closed=right, label=right, convention=e, base=0]
```

To my surprise the *size()* function returns different types depending on sampling frequency:

- if I sample by quarter, I receive **Series**,
- if I sample by year, I receive **DataFrame**.

Code:

```
print(type(freq.resample('Q').size()))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(freq.resample('Y').size()))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

The outputs are also semantically different, so I cannot re-use the same pipeline to process results. I expected that the output object type and the structure of the output data is not dependent on the sampling frequency I used.

**Questions:**

1. Why I am getting different object type as a result of *size()* function,
   when I use different sample frequencies?
2. How can I change code to get the same object type and the same object structure regardless of the specified sampling frequency?

I am using 0.23.4 version of Pandas.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is apparently data-dependent. I boiled it down to 10 records, which causing the change of the output type. I cannot explain why I am getting the different output type here. Sorting values by date does not change the result.

```
u2.dtypes
UPGRADESTRATEGY               object
SCENARIO_STARTDATE    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

This generates DataFrame.

```
print(u2.iloc[-105:-96])
      UPGRADESTRATEGY  SCENARIO_STARTDATE
18645               b 2016-12-20 14:48:57
18646               a 2017-01-07 16:58:44
18647               b 2017-01-11 14:39:58
18648               a 2017-01-10 15:42:22
18649               a 2017-01-10 10:07:34
18650               a 2017-01-12 15:31:14
18651               a 2017-01-13 12:44:02
18652               a 2017-01-13 14:51:59
18653               a 2016-12-12 22:30:01


type(u2.iloc[-105:-96].groupby(["UPGRADESTRATEGY"]).resample('Q', on='SCENARIO_STARTDATE').size())

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

This generates Series.

```
print(u2.iloc[-104:-96])

      UPGRADESTRATEGY  SCENARIO_STARTDATE
18646               a 2017-01-07 16:58:44
18647               b 2017-01-11 14:39:58
18648               a 2017-01-10 15:42:22
18649               a 2017-01-10 10:07:34
18650               a 2017-01-12 15:31:14
18651               a 2017-01-13 12:44:02
18652               a 2017-01-13 14:51:59
18653               a 2016-12-12 22:30:01

type(u2.iloc[-104:-96].groupby(["UPGRADESTRATEGY"]).resample('Q', on='SCENARIO_STARTDATE').size())

pandas.core.series.Series
```

DataFrame output:

```
u2.iloc[-105:-96].groupby(["UPGRADESTRATEGY"]).resample('Q', on='SCENARIO_STARTDATE').size()
SCENARIO_STARTDATE  2016-12-31  2017-03-31
UPGRADESTRATEGY                           
a                            1           6
b                            1           1
```

Series output:

```
u2.iloc[-104:-96].groupby(["UPGRADESTRATEGY"]).resample('Q', on='SCENARIO_STARTDATE').size()
UPGRADESTRATEGY  SCENARIO_STARTDATE
a                2016-12-31            1
                 2017-03-31            6
b                2017-03-31            1
dtype: int64
```

I am out of ideas!

Comment: Hard to know what's going on in your case without a [mcve]. What happens when you add `squeeze=True` as an argument to `groupby` when defining `freq`? Are they both `Series` when you do `.size()`?

Comment: I @ALollz thank you for your fast response! Yes, I'll extend the question with an example. In a meanwhile I provide here the results of applying `squeeze` flag. It is indeed forced the output to be `Series`, but the yearly sampler now renders an incorrect result - the grouping by _UPGRADESTRATEGY_ disappears and the resulting datasets from both categories I have are just stacked one upon eachover.